# How do you include &( specila characters '&') within Twitter share link text? in php

Tags: php, twitter

I'm getting  the text like this:: Come check me out on iRant !!! index.php?path=videopage via @.
But actually i want to get like this :: Come check me out on iRant !!! index.php?path=videopage&vid='123456' via @

```
<a href="https://www.twitter.com/intent/tweet?via=&text=Come check me out on iRant !!! index.php?path=videopage&vid='123456'">twitter</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your values when you want to send them in a url:

```
<a href="https://www.twitter.com/intent/tweet?via=&text=<?php echo urlencode($your_text); ?>">twitter</a>
```

That applies to all values that can contain characters that are not valid in a url.

Comment: @Rameshvemula If the answer solves your problem, you should mark it as accepted (the check-mark below the vote count).